# Sonarqube support for ‘.Net Core’ (with .xproj extention) projects

Tags: sonarqube, .net-core, sonarqube-scan, .xproj

Anyone has any idea on whether ‘.Net Core’ (with .xproj extention) projects are supported by Sonarqube v4.x or v5.x (C# plugin version 5.2)?

Though there is no error message in SonarQube Scanner log file, all our .xproj files are  listed under “Skipped projects” in ProjectInfo.log file and dashboard is showing results only for .csproj files and not for any .xproj files.

Thank you for the your response for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [documentation of the *SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild*](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild?src=breadcrumbs-parent) (which is the scanner to be used for analysing C#/.Net projects in SonarQube) :

> Analysis of ASP.NET vNext projects (i.e. project.json) is currently not supported, refer to [SONARMSBRU-167](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-167)

[EDIT] .Net Core projects now supported since [Scanner for MSBuild v2.3](https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/product-news/news.html#2017-04-13-sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild-2-3-released) (which itself is already old, so just grab the latest)

Comment: if there is a .netcore 1.1 (.xproj) it should be migrated to .netcore 2.0?