# sonar analysis for .net core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.6

Hi all am using sonarqube v5.6.6

**plugins:**

- Sonarqube v5.6.6
- sonar fxcop plugin v1.0
- Sonar c# v6.0

I am trying to do sonar analysis for .Net core(v1.1) project(c# language) build using VS2017 community edition. i searched in net regarding this issue & got few links like [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048060/how-can-i-use-sonarqube-to-scan-an-aspnet-core-1-1-project), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368198/sonarqube-support-for-net-core-with-xproj-extention-projects), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841439/running-sonarqube-against-an-asp-net-core-solution-project) of stackoverflow but all points the sonar 
 [JIRATkt167](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-167) and its states that closed but still i didn't get any idea for how to run the sonar anlysis for .Net core project.

So please suggest me any documents or video to run same.

Please feel free to ask if you need any further details. sample [code](https://github.com/vival30/Sample/blob/master/ConsoleCoreapp.zip)(which i used to do sonar analysis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry its a false alarm i didn't get the point in the [JIRATkt167](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-167) they have moved the issue to new tkt [JIRAtkt310](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-310) & this new tkt is still open & still the issue is not resolved.

Thanks & Regards

Vival